# get position of node use it as the attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have input and there are several `disp-quote` node there.

This is the correct Xpath : `body//sec/disp-quote/p`

Input :

```
<body>
  <sec>
    <disp-quote>
       <p>Test</p>
    </disp-quote>
  </sec>
  <sec>
    <sec>
      <disp-quote>
         <p>Test</p>
      </disp-quote>
    </sec>
  </sec>
<body>
```

Output should be :

```
<context type="QuoteUsed" id="dq001"/>

<context type="QuoteUsed" id="dq002"/>
```

The `id` attribute should use "dq" followed by a 3-digit number that iterates in ascending order (e.g. dq001, dq002, dq003, etc.)

the Tried code :

```
<context type="QuoteUsed">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('dq','')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</context>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your input ?

Comment: @Vebbie Ok I updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check following code:-

```
<xsl:template match="sec/disp-quote/p">
  <context type="QuoteUsed">
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
          <xsl:text>dq</xsl:text><xsl:number level="any" format="001"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </context>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<xsl:for-each select="body//sec/disp-quote/p">
        <context type="QuoteUsed">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('dq',format-number(position(), '000'))"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </context>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or shortly:

```
<context type="QuoteUsed" id="dq{format-number(position(), '000')}"/>
```

---

See: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates